# Непредвиденное исключение в методе

Tags: c#, .net

Есть метод для отсечки по времени выполнения асинхронной задачи, выглядит он вот так:

```
internal static async Task TimeoutAfter(Task task, int timeout)
{
    using (var timeoutCTS = new CancellationTokenSource())
    using (var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout, timeoutCTS.Token))
    using (var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, timeoutTask))
    {
        if (completedTask == task)
        {
            timeoutCTS.Cancel();
            await task;
        }
        else
            throw new TimeoutException("The operation has timed out.");
    }
}
```

В конструкторе формы создана подписка на обработку TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException.

**Суть проблемы:** если переданная в метод задача создает исключение, оно пробрасывается в UnobservedTaskException. До применения этого метода подобного поведения не наблюдалось. Пришлось, на время, использовать заглушку в виде:

```
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (s, args) =>
{
    args.SetObserved();
};
```

**Вопрос:** почему происходит проброс исключений в UnobservedTaskException и как корректно выйти из ситуации?

**Update:**
если заключить метод, в котором вызывается TimeoutAfter, в блок try\catch - то исключение всеравно пробрасывается в UnobservedTaskException.

Comment: подозреваю, что в try catch нужно оборачивать первый await, который `await Task.WhenAny(task, timeoutTask)`

Comment: @Grundy, это некрасиво)

Comment: А зачем так сложно?

Comment: UnobservedTaskException срабатывает при любой ошибке или только после тайм-аута?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, UnobservedTaskException срабатывает при любой ошибке, которая происходит в переданной в Task.WhenAny задаче ( task). Grundy прав. Но лепить туда try\catch как то некрасиво.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Grundy - добавил в вопрос блок update, там обозначил основную суть проблемы. Т.е. даже если даже затрукетчить поверх UnobservedTaskException - исключение всеравно улетает в UnobservedTaskException.

Comment: [Таски не нужно/можно не диспоузить.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/25/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/) И код сразу станет проще.

Comment: **Не воспроизводится**: в ветке без тайм-аута ваш код - рабочий, никакого UnobservedTaskException у меня не возникает.

Comment: А какая у вас версия .NET Framework? Поведение «заброшенных» тасков менялось от версии к версии.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте сначала выясним, что такое unobserved exception. Когда у нас выполняется `Task`, он может в реальности выполняется в другом потоке, отличном от того, в котором мы его ожидаем (а также в нескольких потоках, а также в никаком). Происходящее как часть выполнения `Task`'а исключение не выбрасывается сразу, т. к. при этом пострадает рабочий поток, который является лишь инструментом для выполнения задания. Исключение вместо этого сохраняется в `Task`'е, и будет выброшено, когда на этот `Task` будет сделан `await`. (Ну или `.Wait()`, или запрошен `.Result`.) Таким образом, исключение *доставляется* в ту точку, где результат задания опрашивается.

А что, если результат никто опрашивать не будет? Ведь `await` делать не обязательно? Вот в этом случае исключение «остаётся внутри» `Task`'а.

В .NET 4.0 «ненаблюдённое» исключение в `Task`'е и правда приводило к завершению работы программы. Правда, был предоставлен «последний шанс» для обработки исключения: `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`. В .NET 4.5 поведение по умолчанию [поменялось](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=netframework-4.7#remarks), но его можно включить назад, используя конструкцию

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/>   
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

в вашем `app.config`. Ваш случай, видимо, один из этих.

Для того, чтобы верно обработать эту ситуацию, имеет смысл просто прочитать и проигнорировать исключение. Изящный метод даёт Stephen Toub (один из ключевых разработчиков языка C#) в своей статье [*Tasks and Unhandled Exceptions*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/06/01/tasks-and-unhandled-exceptions/):

```
static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static Task ObserveExceptions(this Task task)
    {
        task.ContinueWith(c => { var ignored = c.Exception; },
            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted |
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously |
            TaskContinuationOptions.DetachedFromParent);
        return task;
    }
}
```

С ним ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
using (var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task.ObserveExceptions(), timeoutTask))
```

(остальная часть такая же, как и раньше).

---

Событие `UnobservedTaskException` возникает, когда рантайм замечает, что у `Task`'а никто не проверил, было ли выброшено исключение, *и никто в будущем не будет проверять*. Как выяснить, что в будущем никто проверять не будет? Очень просто: когда объект `Task`'а убирается сборщиком мусора! В этот момент-то уж точно никто не имеет ссылки на `Task`, а значит, не может проверить его результат. Именно поэтому никакой try/catch вокруг `TimeoutAfter` не помогает: ведь *внутри* `TimeoutAfter` никакого исключения не происходит! (Именно поэтому оно и «не наблюдается».) Чтобы исключение из коробки-`Task`'а проникло наружу, нужно использовать `await`, `.Result`, `.Wait()` или какую-нибудь аналогичную конструкцию.

---

Более красивый вариант предлагает @Pavel Mayorov в комментарии:

```
using (var timeoutCTS = new CancellationTokenSource())
using (var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout, timeoutCTS.Token))
using (var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, timeoutTask))
{
    if (completedTask == task)
    {
        timeoutCTS.Cancel();
        await task;
    }
    else
    {
        task.ObserveExceptions();
        throw new TimeoutException("The operation has timed out.");
    }
}
```

---

Заметьте, что `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` вызывается даже если вы установите `<ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="false"/>`, но [не будет приводить к падению процесса](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/), если вы не вызовете `SetObserved()`:

> To make it easier for developers to write asynchronous code based on Tasks, .NET 4.5 changes the default exception behavior for unobserved exceptions.  While unobserved exceptions will still cause the UnobservedTaskException event to be raised (not doing so would be a breaking change), the process will not crash by default.  Rather, the exception will end up getting eaten after the event is raised, regardless of whether an event handler observes the exception.

Comment: Я бы вызов ObserveExceptions поставил в ветку обработки тайм-аута.

Comment: Кстати, вы уверены что ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions влияет на возникновение события? Я этот флаг не включал - и у меня событие UnobservedTaskException все равно возникало. Насколько я понимаю, настройка ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions  влияет на то, будет ли исключение "прокидываться" дальше этого события если так и не было обработано.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ага, так будет изящнее.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: [Отсюда](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/): _.NET 4.5 changes the default exception behavior for unobserved exceptions.  While unobserved exceptions will still cause the UnobservedTaskException event to be raised (not doing so would be a breaking change), the process will not crash by default._